# Code for connecting to Azure Client for MS Office 365 Graph API

Tags: c#, ssis

Need help writing C# code for connecting to MS Office 365 Graph API. This code will be used in SSIS package. Standard SSIS components don't work due to authentication (need to provide TenantID, ClientID and Client Secret), therefore need to include a custom C# element.

I do have a code from Power BI (M Query) that works, so basically need an equivalent in C#.

"
= () as text =>
let
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & #"Tenant Id" & "/oauth2/token", [Content = Text.ToBinary("client_id=" & #"Client Id" & "&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com" & "&client_secret=" & #"Client Secret" & "&grant_type=client_credentials") ,Headers=[#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded", Accept="application/json"]])),
access_token = Source[access_token]
in
access_token
"
#"Tenant Id", #"Client Id", #"Client Secret" are parameters that I am planning to pass.

Comment: Have you looked around online for an existing solution? I'm sure someone out there may be able to help write some custom code, but this sounds like a problem that has probably already been solved (and likely better than you'll achieve with a C# snippet) Just a random example: https://zappysys.com/blog/calling-office-365-api-using-ssis-graph-api-mail-calendar-contacts-onedrive-excel/

Comment: This is different, because in the given example there is no way to provide the Tenant ID, which I have to. And yes - I did the googling part already.

Comment: Zappysys is actually a paid solution, so unfortunately doesn't work for me.